# Decide whether set is convex, connect and bounded.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

Let $A=\{ \left(x,y,z \right)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2-z^2+1<0\}$. Decide whether set A is:

a) convex (definition i know: Set $A\in \mathbb{R}^k$ is convex set if for all $x,y \in A$ line segment $[x,y]$ is in $A$.

b) connected (set is connected if all points $x,y\in A$ can be connected with a polygonal chain contained in this set)

c) bounded (if it is contained in a ball i.e. there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $r>0$  such that $A\in B\left(x, r \right)$ )

I have no idea how to approach that. It is not easy to sketch such a set, what are the other methods to solve this? Solution does not have to be precise as in this question they require you to answer only YES or NO.

Comment: @CameronBuie Notice that $a<0$, please.

Comment: What do you know of equations of the form $x^2+y^2-z^2+a=0$? What is the relationship between the set of points such that $x^2+y^2-z^2+1=0$ and the given set?

Comment: @Michael: Right you are! My mistake.

Comment: i know that this is a sphere, thus the answer to all will be yes?

Comment: @Krowskir: If it were a sphere, then the answer would be yes. It is not, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so let's begin by thinking about what this shape looks like. Lets say that we set $z$ to some constant value and see what the cross-section looks like.

If $-1\le z\le 1$, then this clearly is empty.

If $\left|z\right|>1$, then we get the open disk $x^2+y^2<z^2-1$ (interior of a circle).

Now, lets look at those questions:

a) Convex: No. Pick a point with positive $z$ and one with negative $z$. The line segment between them will have to go through the plane $z=0$ and there are no such in the set. Thus, said line segment is not in the set

b) Connected: Again no. Pick a point with positive $z$ and one with negative $z$. Any path between them will have to go through a point with $z=0$ and there are no such in the set.

c) Bounded: $z$ can be arbitrarily large, so no.

So, no to all three.